# jQuery loop through articles and delay() a specific article

Tags: jquery, delay

I have a jQuery function which loops through a set of `<article>`-elements:

```
$("article:first").fadeTo(animationTime,1,function() {
    $(this).delay(2000).fadeTo(animationTime,0,function(){ // was 20000
        $(this).find('#delaythisarticle').delay(10000);
        $(this).insertAfter("article:last");
        $("article:last").hide();
        mainSlide(200);
    });
})
```

Now, what I want is to show one article longer than the rest. This article has the ID `#delaythisarticle`. I tried the `delay()` function, but I understood that this does not work when it is not in a jQuery queue. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like using ternary operators.

With this same code:

```
$("article:first").fadeTo(animationTime,1,function() {
    $(this).delay(2000).fadeTo(animationTime,0,function(){ // was 20000
        $(this).find('#delaythisarticle').delay(10000);
        $(this).insertAfter("article:last");
        $("article:last").hide();
        mainSlide(200);
    });
})
```

Replace the `animationTime` with:

```
.fadeTo(($(this).attr("id") == "delayThisArticle") ? 10000 : animationTime)
```

Try and let us know if it works. :)

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm when applied to the `delay()` function: `delay(($(this).attr("id") == "delaythisarticle") ? 10000 : 2000)`. No the `#` should be removed in your syntax.